# accessing the starting element of 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I came across this piece of code. In the cout statement the conditions evaluates to true.

```
   a[10][10]=’h’;
   cout<<(a[0]==*a)&&(*a==0[a]);
```

Accessing an array element/address using `0[a]` is the new thing.
Can somebody please explain this type of notation ?

Comment: A Mathematician will say that it works because addition is commutative.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: my bad. sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Q: I came across some joke code containing the expression 5["abcdef"] . How can this be legal C?

A: Yes, Virginia, array subscripting is commutative in C. [footnote] This curious fact follows from the pointer definition of array subscripting, namely that a[e] is identical to *((a)+(e)), for any two expressions a and e, as long as one of them is a pointer expression and one is integral. The ``proof'' looks like

```
a[e]
*((a) + (e))    (by definition)
*((e) + (a))    (by commutativity of addition)
e[a]        (by definition)
```

This unsuspected commutativity is often mentioned in C texts as if it were something to be proud of, but it finds no useful application outside of the Obfuscated C Contest (see question 20.36).

Since strings in C are arrays of char, the expression "abcdef"[5] is perfectly legal, and evaluates to the character 'f'. You can think of it as a shorthand for

```
char *tmpptr = "abcdef";

... tmpptr[5] ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, `0[a]` has exactly the same meaning as `a[0]`, and both are equivalent to `*a`. See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html).

As long as `a` is a pointer, all these expressions have the same semantics in C++ as they do in C.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` is a pointer to an object, these expressions are always the same:

```
*a

0[a]

a[0]
```

This means these expressions `(a[0]==*a)` and `(*a==0[a])` are also the same and both evaluate to `1`.